# How to send sms in background during a phone call

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I'm developing an app that needs to send some sms and at the same time, make a phone call. The principal problem is if I put the code with normal intents that works but make that phone call and it finish intermediately because the phone starts to send the sms.

My question is:
How can I do the two things at the same time? I've just thought about sending the sms in background but I don't know how to.

Java always make the phone call first, also if the code is not in that order.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using two services. The first one make the call and the second send the messages. My problem was that i'm using the same button in order to start both so did it in that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
`Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);`
`callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneToCall));` 
`callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
`this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(callIntent);`

`Timer timerSMS = new Timer();`
`TimerTask tSMS = new TimerTask() {`
            `@Override`
            `public void run() {`
                `SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();`
                `for (int i = 0; i = 10)`
                 `sms.sendTextMessage(phoneToSMS[i], null, "Hello World", null, null);'
                `}`
            `}`
       `};`
`timerSMS.schedule(tSMS, 1);`
```

It starts after 1 ms. So we can say that it works almost at the same time.